# When to use multiprocessing.Queue over multiprocessing.Pool? When is there a need to use multiprocessing.Queue?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have tried `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` and `multiprocessing.Pool` in multiple deep learning projects. I am having a hard time understanding the `multiprocessing.Queue`, I don't understand its need. Is there a special condition where it is useful.

As an example I have following target function:

```
def process_detection( det_, dims ,classes):

    W = dims[0]
    H = dims[1]
    classes = classes
    boxes = []
    confidences=[]
    classIDs=[]
    classes_pred=[]
    for detection in det_:
                xcenter, ycenter, width, height = np.asarray([W, H, W, H]) * detection[0:4]
                confidence_encoded = detection[5:] # (80,) array
                index_class = np.argmax(confidence_encoded) #index of max confidence
                confidence = confidence_encoded[index_class] # float value of confidence (probability)
                # print(classes)
                class_predicted = classes[index_class] # class predicted

                if confidence > 0.5:
                    if class_predicted == "person":
                        print("{} , {:.2f}".format(class_predicted, confidence))
                        # continue
                        topX = int(xcenter - width/2.)
                        topY = int(ycenter - height/2.)
                        width = int(width)
                        height = int(height)
                        confidence = float(confidence)

                        bbox = [topX, topY, width, height]

                        boxes.append(bbox)
                        confidences.append(confidence)
                        classIDs.append(index_class)
                        classes_pred.append(class_predicted)

    return [boxes, confidences, classIDs, classes_pred]
```

I am using `multiprocessing.Pool.starmap` to process a list of bounding boxes predicted by YOLOv3. The relevant function is below:

```
def main():

    pool = Pool(processes=os.cpu_count()) # make a process pool  for multi-processing

    path = Path("..")
    classes = open(str(path.joinpath("coco.names")), "r").read().strip().split("\n")
    colors_array = np.random.randint(0,255,(len(classes),3),dtype="uint8")
    colors = {cls_:clr for cls_,clr in zip(classes, colors_array)}


    # %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    #                reading the video
    # %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(str(path.joinpath("video_.mp4")))

    _, frame = cap.read()

    if frame is None:
        print(f"FRAME IS NOT READ")
    else:
        # frame = resize(frame, width=500)
        H, W = frame.shape[0:2]

    # %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    #                <model>
    # %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    configPath = path.joinpath("yolov3.cfg")
    weightsPath = path.joinpath("yolov3.weights")


    net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(str(configPath), str(weightsPath))
    ln = net.getLayerNames()
    ln = [ln[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]



    writer = None


    boxes = []
    confidences = []
    classIDs = []
    classes_pred = []

    fps_ = FPS().start()
    i = 0

    while True:
        # pool = Pool(processes=os.cpu_count()) # make a process pool  for multi-processing
        try:
            if writer is None:

                writer = cv2.VideoWriter("./detections.avi", cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MJPG"), int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)), (W, H))
                # after this writer will not be none

            _, frame = cap.read() # reading the frame
            # frame = resize(frame, width=W) # resizing the frame

            blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1 / 255.0, (416, 416),
            swapRB=True, crop=False) # yolov3 version

            net.setInput(blob)

            start = time()
            detections = net.forward(ln)
            end = time()
            print(f"{(end-start):.2f} seconds taken for detection")

            # %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            #                MULTIPROCESSING
            # %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


            results = pool.starmap_async(process_detection, zip(detections, repeat((W,H)) , repeat(classes) ) )

            boxes, confidences, classIDs, classes_pred = results.get()[1]

            #%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            cleaned_indices = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, 0.5 , 0.3) # 0.3 --> nms threshold
            print(f"TOTAL INDICES CLEANED ARE {len(cleaned_indices):00d}")

            if len(cleaned_indices)>0:

                for cleaned_idx in cleaned_indices.flatten():
                    BOX = boxes[cleaned_idx]
                    color = [int(i) for i in colors[classes_pred[cleaned_idx]]]
                    # print(colors[cleaned_idx], cleaned_idx)
                    cv2.rectangle(frame, (BOX[0],BOX[1]), (BOX[0]+BOX[2], BOX[1]+BOX[3]),color, 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
                    text = f"{classes_pred[cleaned_idx]} : {confidences[cleaned_idx]:.2f}"
                    cv2.putText(frame, text, (BOX[0], BOX[1] - 5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                    0.5, color, 2)

            writer.write(frame)
```

(pool is closed OUTSIDE while loop).

- When is the need to use multiprocessing.Queue?
- Can I make this code more efficient using multiprocessing.Queue?

Comment: The Queue is a way to communicate between processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general it is not necessary (nor useful) to use a `Pool` and a `Queue` together.

The way a `Pool` is most useful is to run the same code with different data in parallel on multiple cores to increase throughput. That is, using the `map` method and its variants. This is useful for situations where the calculation done on each data-item is *independent* of all the others.

Mechanisms like `Queue` and `Pipe` are for communicating between different processes.
If you *need* a `Queue` or a `Pipe` in a pool worker, then the calculations done by that pool worker are by definition not independent. At best, that reduces the performance of the `Pool` because the pool workers might have to wait for data to become available. At worst, it might stall the `Pool` completely if all the workers are busy waiting for data to appear from a `Queue`.

---

### How to use a `Pool`

If you expect that all the calculations will take approximately the same time, just use the `map` method. This will return when all calculations are finished. And the returned values are guaranteed to be in the same order as the submitted data.
(Hint: there is little point in using the `_async` methods when the next thing you do is to call the `get` method on the result object.)

If some calculations take (much) longer than others, I would suggest using `imap_unordered`. This will return an iterator that will start yielding results as soon as they are ready. The results will be in the order that they finished, not in the order they were submitted, so you should add some identifier to the result to enable you to tell to which input data the result belongs.